# VBA Update Document after sending a form

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read out something from a website using an excel vba macro.
(MS Office 365/Windows 10/IE Explorer 11)

I navigate to the webpage. This page is a form where I have to confirm a checkbox and press a button. This works all fine, but how can I read out the webpage after the form has been sended? My code:

```
Dim objbrowser As New InternetExplorer
objbrowser.Navigate ("http://www.formdemo.htm")
GoSub SubWaitForIE 'I put the wait for IE loop into a sub
set docFile = objbrowser.Document
vCheckbox = docFile.getElementsByName("agreecheck"): vCheckbox.Click
docFile.getElementById("sendbutton").Click
GoSub SubWaitForIE
```

At this point, the form is transmitted, the result page is loaded.
But how do I get the resultpage in to an object like in

```
set docFile = objbrowser.Document
```

again??

Comment: If result page is the same page, then `set docFile2 = objbrowser.Document`. If it opens in another tab or a pop up window, you will need to find it among all internet explorer processes currently running on your PC.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes things are so simple...

But now I got another issue. When the page is opened, IE want to start a download, too. But IE11 opens a pop that asks me if I want to open the file, save it to disk or abort the download. How can I set IE to always download?

And related to that, I want vba to wait until that download is finished before it performes the next task. Is this possible?

Comment: I suggest creating another thread for this question, as it covers yet different problem and answers can help other users searching for solution to this.

Comment: Will do, thank you!